# Angular 2 call super method from html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I've successfully achieved to inherit a class. I would like to call super method from template but right now what I'm getting is `Cannot read property 'presentModal' of undefined`:

```
@Component({})
class Dia {
    constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    }

    presentModal() {
        const detailModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AgendaDetails, { showDetails: 8675309 });
        detailModal.present();
    }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'dimarts-tab.html',
})
export class Dimarts extends Dia { }
```

and in template:

```
<ion-item text-wrap (click)="super.presentModal()">
```

I've also tried with $super, $parent with no success. The only working solution at this moment is to create the method in `Dimarts` and call super there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`super` is ES6 syntax that cannot be used outside the method where it's used. Given there is `Foo` class that extends `Bar`, `super` keyword is interpreted as `Bar` in `Foo` constructor and static methods and as `Bar.prototype` in instance methods.

```
class Foo extends Bar {
  foo() {
    super.foo()
  }
}
```

will be transpiled to

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Foo, _super);
    function Foo() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Foo.prototype.foo = function () {
        _super.prototype.foo.call(this);
    };
    return Foo;
}(Bar));
```

The attempt to use `super.presentModal()` in template defies the purpose of class inheritance and prototype chains.

Unless `presentModal` is defined in child class, it is inherited from parent class. It should be:

```
<ion-item text-wrap (click)="presentModal()">
```

Comment: Good practice to use `this`: `(click)="this.presentModal()"`

Comment: @YoupBernoulli Not really, this is presumed, unless dynamic key needs to be accessed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152290/using-this-keyword-in-angular-components-template