# Using 'this' keyword in Angular component's template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, angular2-template

Let's say we have a `prop` variable in the component class and we use it via interpolation in the template ([stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ks8ur4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)):

component class:

```ts
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  prop = 'Test';
  ...
}
```

template:

```html
<p>{{ this.prop }}</p>
<p>{{ prop }}</p>
```

Why in Angular it's possible to use `this` keyword in templates without any warnings/error (even in AOT mode)? What's behind it?

**Edit**

According to the remark in the answer: `this` *refers to the component itself for which the template was rendered*. But I can also create a template variable and access to it using `this`:

```html
<input #inp> {{ this.inp.value }}
```

In this case we don't have an `inp` variable in the component class and I still get the access to it using `{{this.inp...}}`. Magic?

Comment: It's optional. I would avoid it.

Comment: What is considered "best practice" in these cases. Should `this` be used to prefix component members?

Comment: @webworm In 99.99% cases there is no `this` keyword in templates to get access to component class properties. I just asked this question to simply figure out - what's going on "behind the scene" when we use `this` keyword in templates and Angular somehow simply avoid it (see the correct answer for more details on that)

Comment: Actually it makes a lot of sense to use "this" in the template to be consistent with the TypeScript file. It's like the missing "vm" that disappeared from AngularJs only better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think somebody can give a very much exact answer here (maybe somebody from Angular CLI team), however the outcome I came to is that the component renderer fully ignores `this` keyword in the places where it seems valid (with some exceptions).

**Proof**

```
<input #heroInput value="0">
This prints the component JSON without heroInput: {{ this | json }}

<input #heroInput value="0">
This prints 0: {{ this.heroInput.value }}

<div *ngFor="let val of [1,2,3]">
  <input #heroInput [value]="val">
  Overrides heroInput with current value: {{ this.heroInput.value }}
</div>

This prints 0: {{ this.heroInput.value }}
```

One can assume from the above that `this` is similar to AngularJS (angular 1) `scope`, where the `scope` contains the component properties.

It does not explain why heroInput is not listed in `this | json` still.

However the following is totally broken:

```
{{ this['heroInput'].value }}
```

It gives an error: cannot get `value` of undefined. It should, not, it must work, unless (the only explanation) `this` is just ignored in every case but

```
{{ this | json }}
```

where it refers to the component, because this is the only way to debug the whole component object from the template. Maybe there are some other exceptions, still.

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9ktym)

Comment: `this['heroInput'].value` is working for me. Should I not use that?

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the component itself for which the template was rendered. On the template you can access only `members` of the component. This means that `this` is implicitly added to each property which you use in the template.

This two accesses are the same - the *2nd* one implicitly use `this` in front of it.

```
<p>{{ this.prop }}</p>
<p>{{ prop }}</p>
```

The same is when you use `this` in the component. When you want to access `prop` in the component you need to prefix it with `this.prop` to inform that you are accessing `property` of the component, not a local variable.

Comment: Nice analogy, but if we have local template variable `<input #inp>` I can still get the access to it using `{{ this.inp.value }}` (updated the question as well). So what's going on in this case ?

Comment: Because you declare a template variable, with `#inp` you can have an access on the template

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3]">{{ this.item }}</div>` also works. weird.

Answer (score 0):

### I felt we can't get a proper explanation on this but,

- I went through a case where i will be creating the members of the component dynamically.
- In here it might go wrong, if i don't use this.member (In my case it was actually `this[member]`).
- Create a member in component like,

  > **`this.members(prop=> this[prop]={})`**
- Usage in template will be like,

  > **`{{this[prop]}}`** will give expected result.
  >   **`{{prop}}`** will not give expected result because 
  >   it will print value of list.