# Why does passing "this" from html become undefined?

Tags: angular

I have an html button.  When I pass "this" in the "onclick" to a function, it says it's the element is "undefined".

I have an html table with a delete button in each row.  I want to delete the row when it is clicked.

Controller:

```
deleteRow(btn) {
  let row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;  //this should be the <tr> row element
  let name = row.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0].innerHTML;
  let table = document.getElementById("nutrient-table");
  table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
};
```

Template:

```
<tr>
  <td>Vitamin C</td>
  <td class="dv"></td>
  <td class="dv">2%</td>
  <td>
    <button class="fa fa-minus" (click)="deleteRow(this)"></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The error message says

> btn.parentNode is undefined

Another place I saw "btn is undefined"

Any ideas?

Comment: You should reread the error message. It doesn't say that `btn` is `undefined`. It says that `btn.parent` isn't a function. You can't call `btn.parent()`. The new error message after your edit says, that `btn.parentNode` is `undefined`.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message, in full please?

Comment: The code snippet in the question doesn't reproduce the error message. Can you fix it?

Comment: The button should look like this `(click)="deleteRow"` and the function should call to `this` since it's the element that is calling it.

Comment: The error message in the browser developer tools console says "ERROR TypeError: btn.parentNode is undefined".  Who was so quick to downgrade my question?  Why?

Comment: I downvoted because your code snippet doesn't reproduce the error message. Try to create a [mcve]. Are you sure the error message comes from this part of your code and nothing important is missing? What is `(click)="deleteRow(this)"`? That's not HTML. Are you using a framework? Is this Angular? If this is Angular, `this` isn't the button element.

Comment: I didn't put the "Run Code Snippet" button on this post, stackoverflow system did.

Comment: What converts the  text value of  the button element's attribute named "(click)" (without the quotation marks) into a function that is called when the button is clicked? Is it something TypeScript does for you?

Comment: It would take me days to create a reproducible example.  This is an angular project.  (click) works just as well as onclick.  The question is generic.  How do you pass an html element to javascript or typescript without that element becoming "undefined"?

Comment: You should mention Angular in your question.

Comment: I was blocked from adding a comment to jabba answer so will add it here: I tried btn.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode but got similar error "ERROR TypeError: btn.nativeElement is undefined".  I've spent 2 days on this problem so I'm so frustrated that this IS a last resort.  Binding is complicated.  It's not a simple table like all the examples.  I need a button on each row to delete it.  I need another button on the bottom to add a new row.  I got the add row to work, but not the delete row.

Comment: Since you're using Angular, `this` doesn't point to the button DOM element, but to the Angular component resp. app in a single component application. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but this is the wrong way. Instead of `this`, you should pass a row index or the ID. If this is the whole template for a dump component that doesn't know its own ID and row index, you could bind a custom delete event and handle it in the parent component.

Comment: You should also fix the question title and the description. `this` doesn't become `undefined`. `this` is either the component or the app. `this.parentNode` is `undefined`, because that's not how Angular works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 'this' keyword in Angular component's template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152290/using-this-keyword-in-angular-components-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular documentation, you should be able to access the button element from within the event handler code in HTML as `$event.currentTarget`, given that for native DOM elements, [`$event` is a  DOM event object](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts#handling-events). Hence you could try

```
<button class="fa fa-minus" (click)="deleteRow($event)">Delete Row</button>
```

and have the handler work out the row from the event object.

Please note I am not an Angular programmer and this approach, if it works, may be anathema to Angular-philes for all I know.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've done that before but forgot about it.  I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Your idea worked!  The trick was the combination of getting the element from the event and then finding its parent and deleting the child.  Like this: '  deleteRow(event) {
    let btn = event.target;
    let tr = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  };'

Answer (score 1):

since you are using angular, this should be much simpler than you are making it. it should probably look something more like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td>Vitamin C</td>
  <td class="dv"></td>
  <td class="dv">2%</td>
  <td>
    <button class="fa fa-minus" (click)="deleteRow(row)"></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach earlier.  The problem is the table is more complicated.  Some rows are not allowed to be deleted, depending on content.  Some cells have different format depending on content. The cells must be editable but in a small input field, not angular's huge ones. You know the "Nutrition Facts" on the side of all food packaging?  I want the form to look just like that, and editable from there.  I know angular has *ngIf directive.  Maybe I missed something.  I'll try again.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: well for a row that you want to delete, that's how you would want to do it. maybe have code in the deleteRow method to determine if its a row that can be deleted or not.